# Ansible: applying tags at role execution

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I'm trying to definitively understand **how tags are applied at role execution in Ansible**.

I read the docs at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-roles and tried with a **test role**:

```
 ~/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks > cat tag-foo.yml
---
- import_tasks: tag-foo.yml
  tags:
    - foo
    - foo2

- import_tasks: tag-bar.yml
  tags:
    - bar

- import_tasks: always.yml
  tags:
    - always

- import_tasks: never.yml
  tags:
    - never
    - nevermind

 ~/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks > cat tag-foo.yml
---
- name: This is tag 'foo'
  debug:
    msg: This is tag 'foo'

 ~/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks > cat tag-bar.yml
---
- name: This is tag 'bar'
  debug:
    msg: This is tag 'bar'

 ~/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks > cat always.yml
---
- name: This is tag 'always'
  debug:
    msg: This is tag 'always'

 ~/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks > cat never.yml
---
- name: This is tag 'never'
  debug:
    msg: This is tag 'never'
```

I created a **test playbook** file:

```
 ~/ansible > cat plays/test.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Execute test role with all tags
      import_role:
        name: test
      tags: foo2

    - name: Execute test role with tag 'foo'
      import_role:
        name: test
      tags:
        - foo
```

What I don't understand is that if I execute the playbook with the foo tag, the role is executed **both times** and not only one time executing only the tasks from `tag-foo.yml` and the `tag-always.yml`:

```
 ~/ansible > ansible-playbook -i test.ini plays/test.yml -l test.domain.local -t foo

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local]

TASK [test : This is tag 'foo'] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'foo'"
}

TASK [test : This is tag 'always'] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'always'"
}

TASK [test : This is tag 'foo'] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'foo'"
}

TASK [test : This is tag 'bar'] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'bar'"
}

TASK [test : This is tag 'always'] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'always'"
}

TASK [test : This is tag 'never'] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'never'"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************
test.domain.local           : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What I want is to **force tags** from a single `import_role` statement without necessarily specifying it in the `ansible-playbook` command.

**Edit:** I tried to replace the `import_role` statement with `include_role` into the playbook adding the `apply` option to apply the `foo` tag:

```
- name: Execute test role with tag 'foo'
  include_role:
    name: test
    apply:
      tags:
        - foo
```

And I replaced `import_tasks` statement in the `main.yml` file of the role with `include_tasks`:

```
---
- include_tasks: tag-foo.yml
  tags:
    - foo
    - foo2

- include_tasks: tag-bar.yml
  tags:
    - bar

- include_tasks: always.yml
  tags:
    - always

- include_tasks: never.yml
  tags:
    - never
    - nevermind
```

But unfortunately nothing changed: the 'bar' task is executed anyway:

```
 ~/ansible > ansible-playbook -i test.ini plays/test.yml -l test.domain.local

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local]

TASK [Execute test role with tag 'foo'] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************************************************
included: /Users/me/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks/tag-foo.yml for test.domain.local

TASK [test : This is tag 'foo'] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'foo'"
}

TASK [test : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************************************************
included: /Users/me/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks/tag-bar.yml for test.domain.local

TASK [test : This is tag 'bar'] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'bar'"
}

TASK [test : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************************************************
included: /Users/me/ansible/roles/internal/test/tasks/always.yml for test.domain.local

TASK [test : This is tag 'always'] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.domain.local] => {
    "msg": "This is tag 'always'"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************
test.domain.local           : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `import_role`, it's static re-use, the tag doesn't condition the import, but is added to every tasks of the imported role.

To condition the execution of the role with a tag, you should use a dynamic re-use with the `include_role`.

More documentation on import vs include: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-files-and-roles

Tags mechanism is made to be set through CLI.
If you want to define different behavior of role through playbook, `vars` and `when` are better option:

```yaml
- include_role: my_role
  vars:
     only_foo: True

# in my_role:
- debug:
     msg: Only on foo
  when: only_foo
```

Comment: Nothing changes if I replace import_role with include_role and add the 'apply' parameter: I see 'foo', 'bar' and 'always' tasks executed, I expect that 'bar' is not executed if I pass the 'foo' tag..

Comment: Can you add in your question the new playbook you tried?

Comment: Also, same thing applies to `import_task` vs `include_task`

Comment: Yes, I've even replaced 'import_tasks' with 'include_tasks' into the main.yml file of the role

Comment: Humm, misread the definition of `apply`. It does add the tag to all tasks of role. You **need** to set tags on the cli.

Comment: So I cannot set an "independent" playbook, I need to specify tags on the CLI.. Bad bad bad! I will lose count of times I will miss to specify the correct tag and the entire role will be executed.. Let's make a different role only for these things!

Comment: To conditionnaly execute tasks of a role without using tags, you can simply call the role while specifying vars, then use `when` on tasks depending on the vars.

Comment: Yes, but I consider this a workaround and not really a solution. Vars have a completely different purpose.

Comment: It's not, vars are the way to variabilize the execution, they are made for this use. It's more that tags are not for the use you're trying to use them.

Comment: I don't completely agree with you. I think that vars are used to configure the play, and tags are used to decide what part of the play/role needs to be run (you could run it completely but that time you don't need so you can save time). And I think the purpose of play is to avoid 'thinking' what you need to run because it's already configured in it. For this reasons, vars and tags on CLI are not good for this specific use case.